# Finding a differentiable function

Tags: calculus

I need to find an infinitely differentiable function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which is zero for all negative values and nonzero fo all positive values.

Thank you in advance

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/98577/8581

Comment: A standard example is $f(x)=e^{-1/x}$ if $x>0$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{rcl} 0 &\mbox{if} & x\leq 0 \\ \exp\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)&\mbox{if}&x>0\end{array}\right.$$
is a good candidate. For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have:
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\exp\left(-1/x^2\right) = p(1/x) \exp\left(-1/x^2\right)$$
where $p$ is a polynomial, so:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{d^n}{dx^n}\exp\left(-1/x^2\right) = \lim_{z\to +\infty} p(z)\,e^{-z^2} = 0.$$

Comment: Is there a way to show that this function is infinitely differentiable ?

Comment: @user43418: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function