# Can a monotone decreasing function intersect $y=-x$ on a set of more than measure $0$?

Tags: real-analysis

Can a monotone decreasing continuous function intersect $y=-x$ on a set of more than measure $0$ unless it equals to $y=-x$ on an interval?

I am unsure whether something like Cantor's function can be massaged into satisfying this property. This comes from a research question in an applied area. Maybe I will need to prove more properties about the original function.

Comment: Take a fat Cantor set $C \subset [0,1]$ with $0,1\in C$. Set $f(x) = -x/2$ for $x < 0$, $f(x) = -1-(x-1)/2$ for $x > 1$, and $f(x) = -x$ for $x\in C$. On each open interval of $[0,1]\setminus C$, fill the gap by a scaled and translated copy of $x\mapsto -x^2$. Then $f(x) = -x \iff x\in C$, and $f$ is (strictly) monotonically decreasing.

Comment: @DanielFischer urgh... Thanks

Comment: @DanielFischer but doesnt the cantor set have measure 0?

Comment: I said to take a **fat** Cantor set, that means of positive measure.

Comment: Ah, i see, i did not know what one of those was. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a [fat Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) $C \subset [0,1]$ with $0,1\in C$. Set 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}-x/2\quad &\text{for $x < 0$}, \\ 
-1-(x-1)/2 \quad & \text{for $x > 1$}, \\
-x\quad & \text{for $x\in C$.} \end{cases}$$ 
On each open interval of $[0,1]\setminus C$, fill the gap by a scaled and translated copy of $x\mapsto -x^2$. Then $f(x) = -x \iff x\in C$, and $f$ is (strictly) monotonically decreasing. -- [Daniel Fischer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1318377/can-a-monotone-decreasing-function-intersect-y-x-on-a-set-of-more-than-measur#comment2678561_1318377)

---

I will add another argument, not self-contained.  For every closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ there exists a [$C^\infty$-smooth function which vanishes only on that set](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/98577/147263). Let $\phi$ be such a function for the aforementioned fat Cantor set $C$.  Since $C$ is bounded, we can make $\phi'$ bounded on $\mathbb{R}$. Then for sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$, the function $f(x)=\epsilon\phi(x)-x$ is the desired example.